# Conditional sentences

Tags: grammar

What type of conditional sentences should be used in a context like this?

(This person graduated from school many years ago.)

You know, my mother went to school and said that until she(the teacher) had apologised I wouldn't have attended her classes.

Comment: This sounds like a school assignment. Could you say why you believe the sentence you quote is right or wrong? And perhaps show it's a quote? You only need the relevant part of the story, "My mother said that until the teacher had apologised I wouldn't have attended her classes."

Comment: I thought it is the third type of conditional as it refers to a situation in the past. One of my penpals and I were talking about school and I told her about 'the worst teaher' I ever had at school.I was not sure if I chose the right conditional.

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/316123/2085)/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we try conditionals, I think we could do with some simple reported speech.

This is the context I inferred from your question (please correct me if I'm wrong):

- Direct Speech

> My mother went to school and said (to the teacher): "*Until you
>   apologize, my daughter won't attend your classes.*"

- Reported Speech

> You know, my mother went to school and told my teacher that until she
>   **apologized**, I **wouldn't attend** her classes.

I suppose because the sentence is part of an ongoing narrative, it would be enough to just use reported speech and its tenses rule.

But if we isolate your target sentence, you can employ your past conditional:

> My mother went to school and talked to my teacher. If she **hadn't
>   apologized**, I **wouldn't have attended** her classes.

Comment: Those were exactly my mother's words. You are right. Thanks :) But since it's not a part of an ongoing activity I will use 'hadn't apologized' and 'wouldn't have attended' forms. Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: What I mean by ongoing narrative is, inside the story that you're narrating to your penpal, your mother's condition is actually still in the middle of the event. As in: go to school >>> talk >>> condition given. They're all in one sentence. Break the ideas down into separate sentences and you can use the past conditional.

Comment: Now it's clear to me.