# English Conditionals and "would"

Tags: conditionals, would, deontic-vs-epistemic, protasis, will-would-meaning-wanting-to

I'm having a discussion with my wife on [English conditionals](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/).

She says we cannot have "would" in a hypothetical *if* statement:

> If I *would* want to change my address, should I let you know?

She says that "would" can only occur in the second part (as in Type 2).

If this is the case, is there then no way to describe "a hypothetical situation in which I would want to change my address" as conditional?

I feel like this sentence is different from:

> If I want to change my address, should I let you know?

Then again, maybe it is just that I'm confused with how we would say it in Dutch.

And what about if it is the change, not the wanting to change, that is hypothetical? In other words:

> If I would change my address, should I let you know?

Comment: "If I would want" occurs ~25 million times on google.

Comment: I would say "If I were to [want to] change my address, should I let you know?"

Comment: (1) Why tell someone about your _wish_ to change your address? (2) One can write just about anything. Arguably, 'If I would want to ...' is not ungrammatical, but [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=If+I+would+want+to%2CIf+I+wanted+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIf%20I%20would%20want%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIf%20I%20wanted%20to%3B%2Cc0) give a good indication of how many people consider it a good choice, in spite of Pascal's data.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I'd say "I may change my address soon. Do you want to have my new one if I do?"

Comment: The natural way to say it would be “If I wanted to change my address…”. _If_ is normally followed by a verb in the simple past in hypothetical statements (or past subjunctive in counterfactual ones). As far as I know, this is the same in Dutch. So “if I changed my address” = _als ik mijn adres wijzigde_; “if I wanted to change my address” = _als ik wilde mijn adres wijzigen_; “if I would want to change my address” = _als ik zou mijn adres wijzigen willen_ (?).

Comment: There are prescriptivist rules about when someone should use "should" vs "would" in such cases, but I gave up trying to remember them about 50 years ago.  However, in your example I'd choose "should" instead of "would".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "Als ik mijn adres zou willen wijzigen, moet ik dan ...".

Comment: @PascalvKooten "If I would want" does not occur millions of times on Google; Google guesses at that number, but it will only show you 68 instances. Of those, 44 are not conditionals but *if* in the sense *whether*;  2 are *as if* constructions; 2 are habitual or volitive *would*, and 10 are from non-native speakers. Google shows you only 10 uses by native speakers.

Comment: @StoneyB Shocking! I never knew that this estimation of google could be so wrong. I wouldn't be surprised if it would yield only 1 million results, but 68 instances is really a huge factor.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Great resource, very useful in comparison to the simplified google approach. I'll use Ngrams from now on. "May" is a nice example.

Comment: Re: Google—Try Googling the phrase _in quotes_. Otherwise it just finds all pages where those words occur anywhere on the page, rather than it that order. Re: Dutch—Please excuse my butchering of the Dutch language—I never could figure out the word order in subordinate Dutch clauses. Seems to be somewhere between German, Scandiwegian, and English, but I’ve never quite grasped it. The point was: can you actually say both “Als ik mijn adres wilde wijzigen, moet ik dan het u laten weten?” **and** “Als ik mijn adres zou willen wijzigen, moet ik dan het u laten weten?”, with different meanings?

Comment: I don't think anybody knows where Google gets that silly number at the top -- including anybody at Google.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I *did* google with "quotes": you will see 25 million like I do. I wouldn't say "Als ik mijn adres wilde wijzigen".

Comment: No, I get exactly 70 hits with quotes (didn’t check without quotes before, but I see now that the number is about 500 million then). Although… when I try in Chrome or Firefox, it gives me nearly 25 million hits, even if I copy-paste the URL from Safari (which gives me only 70 hits). That is a new level of Google bizarreness to me. Regardless: This does seem to be a genuine difference between Dutch (plus German?) and other Germanic languages—the simple past and the conditional [can both appear both in protasis and apodosis](http://www.dutchgrammar.com/en/?n=Verbs.Re22). Didn’t know that.

Comment: @PascalvKooten this happens all the time, and it was a shock when I discovered this HUGE difference between what Google predicts and the *actual* results. Not only must you close the phrase in quotes, but you have to look at the string of number pages below. Click at page no. 7 or 8 and you see the results dropping like pears from a tree. [**"If I would want"**](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22If+I+would+want%22&start=70)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I realised it indeed. Saying "you will see 25 million like I do" was only referring to google having it wrong :) Indeed, it's a HUGE difference and it has been an eye opener not to trust google like that. The Ngrams page seems solid, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for getting to the bottom of both the bizarre googleness and confirming there is an actual difference between Dutch and English :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there then no way to describe "a hypothetical situation in which I would want to change my address" as conditional?

Yes, there is a way. To express a hypothetical present time situation, use the past tense verb form in the if-clause:

> If I wanted to change my address, should I let you know?

If the change is hypothetical:

> If I changed my address, should I left you know?

For a hypthetical past time situation, use the past perfect in the if-clause and use the perfect in the other clause:

> If I had wanted to change my address, should I have let you know?
>   If I had changed my address, should I have let you know?

---

The use of *would* in the if-clause ranges from colloquial to "acceptable" (i.e., "standard) in American English. The answer by StoneyB seems to cover the uses generally recognized as standard. However, I'm not sure if it includes the situation where the action in the in-clause comes *after* the action in the other clause, as in

> If it would make her dance I would give her a dollar.

Here, the dancing comes after the dollar-giving.

In addition, *Longman Exams Dictionary, grammar guide* is said to include the following example:

> The blockades wouldn't happen if the police would be firmer with the strikers.

Here is *conditional would* in the if-clause of a typical conditional sentence. I don't have a copy of this book, but it is cited in the Wikipedia article on the [English conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#cite_note-6) and [elsewhere](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/conditional-2-would-in-if-clause-if-you-would-send-me-the-confirmation-order-id-be-very-grateful.148123/#post-11464483) (although it's possible that Wikipedia is dependent on the WordReference link as its source). The same WordReference link also cites *Practical English Usage* (3rd edition) as saying

> Conditional would is sometimes used in both clauses of an if-sentences. This is very informal, and is not usually written. It is common in spoken American English:
>
> It would be good if we'd get some rain.
>   How would be feel if this would happen to our family?

Thus, it really depends on the register (formal vs informal) that you are asking about to answer your question in general. For colloquial American English, at least, the use of *conditional would* in if-clauses is used by some and apparently accepted in one sentence by Longman in written English.

However, I don't know of any American who'd say your example sentence (*If I would want to change my address, should I let you know?*).

Comment: "if the police would be firmer"... 'would be' is not the conditional of 'be' but the past subjunctive of the modal auxiliary 'will' meaning 'to be willing to do something' + the bare infinitive of 'be': "if the police were willing to be firmer".

Answer (score 4):

*Will* and *would* are rare in the protases (*if* clauses) of conditional constructions. They are acceptable in only a few circumstances:

- In actualization conditionals when *will/would* has a volitive sense, equivalent to "be willing":

  > If you will get the pizza I'll pick up the beer.
  >   If you would get the pizza I could pick up beer on my way over.
- In actualization conditionals when *will* has a habitual sense—it's emphatic and implies obstinacy:

  > If you **will** ask smart-ass questions you must expect smart-ass answers.
- In inference conditionals when *will/would* designates a future contingency accepted (even if perhaps only provisionally) as true:

  > If, as you say, the auditors will be here tomorrow, we'd better get to work cooking the books.
  >   John declared that if the auditors would be there the next day they'd better get to work on the books.

I have always suspected that the reason for excluding *will/would* from the protases of actualization conditionals is that the condition must be parsable as **prior** to the consequence. This doesn't apply in inference conditionals since we can draw inferences about prior events from subsequent ones.

Comment: Good! I’d forgotten about your final example, the backshifted version of *If they will be here tomorrow, then...*

Comment: Not just the past time/reported speech (where backshifting occurs), of course, but actual non-past time: *If it would make her dance, I'd give her a dollar.* The dancing comes after the dollar-giving. @tchrist

Comment: @Clare O Nifty! I'm going to have to puzzle over that one.

Answer (score 3):

English modals are subtle beasts, and nearly all forms can and do occur in different parts of conditionals, but with nuanced meaning. [Obligatory crosslink.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/316142/2085)

## If you would

Remember that *If you would X* always means *If you wish/want to X* , as in

> If you would please take your seats, then we can get started.

Because this is talking about current desires, it is in the present, despite the preterite inflection of *would*.  All uses of *would* in the “if” part mean that, as far as I’m aware. Sentences like

> If you would like to help us, do please give us a call.

are perfectly normal. But this is never a hypothetical.  It means

> If you do wish to help us, do please give us a call.

But it uses the backshifted *would* to take the edge off of it and make it seem more polite, less required.  It softens the impending imperative that way, since blunt imperatives are always at risk of seeming too pushy.

German speakers regularly get this confused in English and try to use a hypothetical *would* in the “if” part, which is “not allowed”. Perhaps some Dutch speakers do as well, and this is what your wife was warning you about.

## If you could

With *could*, two possibilities exist, one volitional in the here-and-now, the other hypothetical in the might-yet-be.

The first occurs when *If you could X* means *If you can/are able to X*, softened by backshifting *can* to *could*.  Here it remains a matter of volition, of wishes and wants.

> If you could please take your seats, then we can get started.

As you see, this is talking about the present, not about the past or future. And it is not a hypothetical at all, but talking about a want or a wish in the present in the same way that *If you would* always does.

But with *could*, that’s not the only possibility. *Could* can also signal a hypothetical, and the hypotheticals take a past tense form, or the old imperfect subjunctive *were* in the case of *be*.

The counterfactual version of *could* takes a different “then” part:

> If she could get off work tomorrow, would she still need a babysitter?
>
> If she were able to get off work tomorrow, would she still need a babysitter?

Notice the *would* in the “then” part there.  This is a paired hypothetical.

## If you should

On the other hand, *If you should X* is a more indirect way of using a simple present tense version.

- If he falls, call a doctor.
- If he happens to fall, call a doctor.
- If he should fall, call a doctor.
- Should he fall, call a doctor.
- If he should happen to fall, call a doctor.
- Should he happen to fall, call a doctor.
- Should he chance to fall, call a doctor.

Notice those are all imperatives in the “then” part. Here’s a literary use, because real examples are always best:

> **Should you chance to see** a knight laugh, or smile, or even, look you, arch his brows, or purse his mouth, or in any way show surprise that I should uphold the Lady Mary, **you will take** particular note of his name, his coat-armor, and his lodging.
>
> [—Arthur Conan Doyle, *The White Company*](http://www.classic-literature.co.uk/scottish-authors/arthur-conan-doyle/the-white-company/ebook-page-73.asp)

Notice that the “then” part is using the modal *will* in its deontic imperative mode there, not in its epistemic future mode.

All that notwithstanding, you should please be aware that that citation’s second use of *should* in the subordinate clause governed by *show surprise that* is something else altogether, the sort of thing other European languages will often use a special subjunctive inflection for, should one be available in them.*

---

<sub>* And yes, those really are two more completely different *shoulds*. I did that on purpose.</sub>

Comment: +1 I detest the 'n-conditionals'; but every time I answer one of these questions I understand why teachers use them: to avoid spending their entire careers explaining the unending subtle discriminations you have to draw whenever you talk about either conditionals or modals!

Comment: The examples and crosslink are very useful.