# If we were... everyone would be able to hear what I was saying

Tags: conditionals, future

I wrote the following and was asked to justify my use of "would" vs "will" and "was" vs "am":

"If we were to Skype, everyone in my office would be able to hear what I was saying."

Was what I wrote correct or incorrect? And either way, why?

Thank you so much!

Comment: See if this helps: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56876/future-tense-in-conditional-clauses?rq=1

Comment: And regarding *would*: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/365242/english-conditionals-and-would?rq=1

Comment: "If **we** were to Skype, everyone in **our** office would be able to hear what **we** were saying." Or, "If **I** were to Skype, everyone in **my** office would be able to hear what **I** was saying."

Comment: @ Mahmud Koya, no that would change my meaning. The Skype in question would be between me, in "my" office, and someone else in a different location. So it is not "our" office. And assuming the person wears headphones, it is not what "we" were saying that would be overheard.

Answer (score 1):

The [subjunctive mood](http://grammarist.com/grammar/subjunctive-mood/) is
"used to explore conditional or imaginary situations. It can be tricky to use, which partially explains why many speakers and writers forgo it. But it’s quite useful (and aesthetically pleasing, at least to us), and careful users of English should do their part to preserve it."

Your sentence is a hypothetical of the if-then variety.

As a side note, I also agree with your use of "we" and "my". The "I" implies that your Skyping partner is muted or (more likely) that you are using headphones. Otherwise, I'd go with "we" there.