# What type of conditional is "If you're going to… you've got to..."?

Tags: conditionals

In a cartoon (Peanuts) I saw the conditional 'If you're going to get any joy out of being depressed, you've got to stand like this...'.

Can you explain me why it is the ‘first conditional’?

[image: image of Peanuts comic]

Comment: This just shows that ESL teachers are incorrect when they say that there are only three (four? five?) conditionals in English, and try to fit all conditionals to these templates. (Although I understand why they do it — simplifying complicated stuff makes it much easier to teach.)

Comment: @PeterShor You know, I actually think it’s a veiled rewrite of condition type #IV from [this list of conditional types](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/316142/2085). :)

Comment: @tchrist: I don't think it's the same. When you try to rewrite it with "will", you get "If you will get any joy out of being depressed, you need to stand like this," which doesn't really convey the same meaning, that standing like this ***causes*** you to get joy out of being depressed. Add another one to your list.

Comment: @PeterShor My thinking was that *have to* is like *must* for the second part, and for the first part *will* and *going to* are pretty close, although I did mean *will* in the volitional sense for #IV and *going to* is more of an epistemic thing. I'm happy to add more to the list though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on ELL (though it's too old to migrate now).