# What tense is "In the future, I would like to..."

Tags: grammar

I'm thinking future conditional, is that right? Or is it second conditional? Thanks very much!!

Comment: The only tensed verb in your example is the **past tense** "would". Conditional is not a tense; it's a category of adjunct (adverbial). And there is no future tense in English.

Comment: Okay thanks Bill, understood. A student has said that sentence, could I describe it as good use of the second conditional?

Comment: Difficult to tell from only part of the sentence.

Comment: Just for some context,I'm trying to pick out a list of strengths from her spoken English. She said "In the future I would like to open my own massage centre."

Comment: This is not [a conditional](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/316142/2085) as there is neither protasis nor apodosis here.

Comment: Okay thanks, understood. Would it be okay to describe it as good use of imagined future?