# Question about the main clause of conditionals

Tags: conditionals

I know the four types of conditionals. In the *if* clause, I know that “if” could be replaced by “when” and “should”. On the other hand, I do not know if this would be possible with the main clause. Can we replace the word “would” with other words, like “should or “could”?

Comment: The so-called four conditionals are simply four common patterns for expressing predictions and hypotheses. Patterns 2 and 3 use _would_ in the main clause.  But there are numerous other ways to predict and hypothesise, and I don't think it is helpful to try an allocate these alternatives into one of the 4 canonical conditionals. User @tchrist has identified 277 English conditional sentences. Here is his list: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316123/how-many-conditional-sentence-types-are-possible

Comment: Preliminary point: "if" is a preposition, so the protasis is not a clause but a PP with "if" as head and a content clause as its complement. Replacing "if" with "when" normally changes the meaning. "Would" and "should" can be used: "If you are in town, you really should call in on Ed" / "If you are in town, would you pick up the dry-cleaning".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. Here are a few examples:

> 1. If someone calls, you **should** tell them I'm out.
> 2. If you told me what you need, I **could** possibly help you.

Please note that "*would*", "*should*" and "*could*" bear different meanings. They are not interchangeable.

Comment: *might* works, too — *If you asked your boss, he might give you a raise*.

Comment: @PeterShor exactly.

Comment: @Enguroo Thank you. Will you be kind enough to specify on what type of conditionals they are? I’m new to this topic. My guess is your first example is the zero conditional? For your example number 2, I think it’s the type 2 conditional. I’m only making inferences based on the tenses of the main and if clauses. Also, May I ask for a reference for the word swap for the main clause? Please and Thank you!

Comment: @Enguroo You mentioned that the second example is a 1st conditional, why is the if clause in the simple past? Shouldn’t it be on the simple present tense?https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/type-1-conditional/

Comment: @Nathan Right you are! The first is zero, and the second is, well, second, not first.

Answer (score 0):

### Let's go down into the language.

---

> 1. If you come, I go:
>
> > > Conjunction + noun + verb[1], noun + verb[1]

---

> 2. If you come, I will go:
>
> > > Conjunction + noun + verb[1], noun + modal verb[1] + verb[1]

---

> 3. If you came, I would go:
>
> > > Conjunction + noun + verb[2], noun + modal verb[2] + verb[1]

---

> 4. If you had come, I would have gone
>
> > > Conjunction + noun + auxiliary verb[3] + verb[3], noun + modal verb[2] + auxiliary verb[1] + verb[3]

---

*- [Auxiliary verbs](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/auxiliary-verbs) are so called because they help to form the various tenses, moods, and voices of other verbs. The principal ones are be, do, and have.*

*- There is a further set of auxiliary verbs known as [modal verbs](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/auxiliary-verbs) or modal auxiliary verbs. These combine with other verbs to express necessity, possibility, intention, or ability. The modal auxiliary verbs are must, shall, will, should, would, ought (to), can, could, may, and might.*

---

*- A [conjunction](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/conjunctions) (also called a connective) is a word such as and, because, but, for, if, or, and when. Conjunctions are used to connect phrases, clauses, and sentences.*

---

- [1] = present participle
- [2] = past tense
- [3] = past participle

---

`Then it could be something like:`

> **Example: We would have helped him together, when you had arrived.**

Comment: "If" is a preposition, so "if you come" is a PP with "if" as head and the content clause "you go" as its complement. Modern grammar makes so much more sense!

Comment: "If" is a conjunction - https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/if @BillJ

Comment: No, in modern grammar it's a preposition: reference The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002). Quote: "The conditional adjunct consists of a PP with _if_ as head and a content clause as complement".  See here:[link](https://dspace.aab-edu.net/bitstream/handle/123456789/702/79502760-48ba-46b9-ba57-e8c4995546c5.pdf?sequence=10&isAllowed=y). See p6

Comment: "**Pre**position" contains the prefix **"pre-"** which means *before (in time, place, order, degree, or importance)*. ***"Preposition" is a type of words indicates or places direction or position for other words.*** *`The word "If" doesn't do such things.`*

Comment: Did you read what I said? Or look at the link? It's all there if you care to look!

Comment: Whatever, **"when"** is still considered a conjunction, and you can take it to replace **"if"** in every conditional clause. @BillJ

Comment: Really? "When you're in town, pick up the dry-cleaning and "If you're town ..." have different meanings -- the former is a temporal adjunct, not a conditional one. (Btw, modern grammar takes "when" also as a preposition").

Comment: What I mean is the preposition **`"if"`** can be replaced by the conjunction **`"when"`**, and the sentence will be still considered a conditional clause. Of course, the meaning will be changed.

Comment: The tern 'conditional' expresses meaning. The prepostions "if" and "when" head phrases with different meanings. In "[When you're in town], please collect the dry-cleaning", the bracketed expression is not a conditional adjunct but a temporal one.