# Type 2 conditional "If we liked to..." or "If we would like to..."

Tags: grammar

Normally, type 2 conditional follows syntax: If [simple past clause], [present conditional clause]. For example: *If we had high accuracy, we would need a lot of processing power.*

But is it possible to use "like" in simple past: *If we **liked** to increase accuracy, we **would** need more processing power.*

I tried to search these kind of expressions (*if we liked ... we would ...*) in internet, and I noticed that it is very very rare. However, there exist millions of expressions like: *If we **would like** [to do something] we **would** [do something].*

So, it seems like in case of "like" it is preferred to use "would" both in if clause and main clause:
*If we **would like** to increase accuracy, we **would** need more processing power.* But this is not according to type 2 conditional, or is it?

Comment: The issue here is not so much about conditional syntax but about the difference between _to like_ (which has various forms) and _would like (to)_ (which has only one). If you replace _would like_ with the equivalent tensed verb _want_, then you can construct regular conditional 1 & 2 sentences: _If we want to..., we will need..._ or _If we wanted to..., we would need..._. But _would like_ does not change form between 1 & 2.

Comment: There is no difference between "if we had" and "if we liked", so it is not clear what the question is about.

Comment: @Shoe I do not understand what is your point. So, are you just saying the same what I asked that it is better to use expression "If we would like to increase accuracy, we would need more processing power" instead of "If we liked to increase etc." ?

Comment: @RustyCore But of course there is a difference. Firstly, in this case I cannot say "If we had..." Well, of course I could change the whole expression to be different, but I am not asking for alternative ways for this particular expression. I want to know how I can use "like" with type 2 conditional. So, without "like" I could say "If we increased accuracy, we would need etc." But I want to express this in a more subtle way, to express DESIRE: "If we DESIRED to increase accuracy, etc." But instead of "desire" just using "like".

Comment: _We like to_ increase accuracy = it gives us pleasure to increase accuracy. _We would like to_ increase accuracy = we want/desire to increase accuracy. Are you trying to express pleasure or desire here?

Answer (score 1):

Since no one is interested to answer this, I try to answer myself according to the comments.
It seems that both options are valid: "*If we liked to* ..." and "*If we would like to* ...". However, they have semantic difference: The former, "liked to", implies pleasure of doing something, and the latter, "would like to", implies desire to do something.
In my case, the purpose was to express desire; therefore, the latter is the preferred option.

My only concern, which I still would like someone to give a definitive answer, is that to me this does not qualify as type 2 conditional, where the if-sentence should have only a simple past tense: "liked". Now both if- and main sentence include "would" conditional, that is against the rule: *If we **would like** to increase accuracy, we **would need** more processing power*.

So, if I really can use "would" conditional in both, why it is wrong to say: *If I **would have** more money, I **would buy** a better car*.
Why "would like" is ok, but "would have" is not? Isn't there any logic in English? I suppose that is the reason why English people did not understand the original question either.

Comment: it might help, as a starting point, to stop thinking in terms of type 0,,1,2, mixed conditionals and start thinking in terms of real and unreal/past and present conditionals. in actual language use, native English speakers do not adhere to the artifical constructs given by the type 0,1,2,mixed categories, were are imposed upon the language (ostensibly as a teaching aid to second/foreign language students) and do not describe reality

Comment: please see (1) https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316123/how-many-conditional-sentence-types-are-possible and (2) https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65796/difference-between-if-present-will-infinitive-and-if-present-would, especially the ELTJ article referred to, which is here: (3) http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf

Comment: in fact, there is nothing that prevents anyone from saying "if I would have more money..." but this gets more into the usage and meaning of "would" than it does of conditionals

Comment: It is nothing to do with the conditionals at all in a literate English. It is an informal spoken way to ask for something politely or informal Conditional 2. You may use it in a corner shop for buying crisps and soda, or when applying for food stamps, but be careful not to speak so when interviewing for a decent job or something like it.