# What is the appropriate pairing of verb forms here?

Tags: tenses, modal-verbs

Here is the sentence:

> If we all choose a personal or ceramic cup, we could save 40,000 pounds of CO2 emissions per year.

Am I wrong to think that "choose" and "could save" are an incorrect pairing? I think it sounds better to use one of the following:

> If we all choose ... we can save ...
>
> If we all chose ... we could save ...
>
> If we were to choose ... we could save ...

Comment: Yes, I think your suggested options are better.

Comment: They mean different things. "If we all choose a personal or ceramic cup, we can save 40,000 pounds of CO2 emissions per year" is stating a firm conviction that if we take the action, the savings must (realistically, are [very?] likely to), and certainly are enabled to, follow. //  "If we all choose a personal or ceramic cup, we could save 40,000 pounds of CO2 emissions per year" is saying "If we do A, B could possibly follow" It's not far from   "If we all chose a personal or ceramic cup, we could save 40,000 pounds of CO2 emissions per year", but the latter sounds less hectoring.

Comment: Because a current action would bring future change, it seems best to use "if we choose, we could...." Also, it might be best to keep the person/people and cup/cups in agreement: "If everyone chooses a personal cup..." or "if we all choose personal cups..." And finally, rather than "save" emissions, I'd "eliminate" or "reduce" or "prevent" them.

Comment: please see [how many conditional sentence types are possible?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316123/how-many-conditional-sentence-types-are-possible)